# How can I get a character to walk on a moving platform in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a moving platform in a 2D Sidescroller built in Unity 2020.1

The Moving Platform translates between two points using the MoveTo method. It does not have a RigidBody2D component.

I attach the Player to the platform by making it the child of the platform using OnCollisionEnter2D and OnCollisionExit2D to parent the Player to the parent and reset to null respectively. Works great.

I'm using the CharacterController from Standard Assets.

The problem:

The player just walks in place when I try to move him back and forth on the platform.

What I've tried so far:

1. Changing the current velocity of the player by adding a constant to the x dimension of it's move vector.
   Works kinda sorta but that constant needs to be huge to get it to move even a little bit. It's a huge kluge that violates every sense of coding propriety.
2. Put a RigidBody2D on the platform. Make it kinematic so it doesn't fall to the ground when I land on it. Move the platform via "rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y)";

2a) Attempt to make the Player a child of the kinematic platform.
Player is made a child, but it doesn't move with the platform as expected. I believe that this is because both objects have RigidBody2D components, which I gather don't play well together based on what I've read.

2b) Attempt to add the platform's moving vector to the player's movement vector to make him stay in one place. Player stays stationary to make sure he stays fixed on the platform.
No dice.

I'm all out of ideas. Perusing videos on making player's stick to moving platforms all use the platform to move the player from place to place, without expecting that the game may want the player to move back and forth on the platform as the platform is moving.

I can't believe that this isn't a solved problem, but my Google foo isn't getting me any answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fairly newbie to Unity and C# but I wanted to help so I tried simulating your game for a solution and I didn't run into any problems using this script as the Player movement  (you can modify variables as u like, add a separate variable for jump speed to make it smoother etc)

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

Rigidbody2D rb;

float speed = 7f;

Vector3 movement;

public bool isOnGround;
public bool isOnPlatform;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
    transform.position += movement * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    Jump();
}

void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isOnGround || Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isOnPlatform)
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * speed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

}

Also add an empty child object to your Player gameObject and add a BoxCollider2D at his feet, narrow it down on Y axis [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXfQI.png)

also attach this script to that child gameObject to check if player is on the ground(tag ground collider objects with new tag "Ground") so u don't jump infinitely while in the air OR if the player is on the platform(tag platform collider objects with "Platform") so  you're still able to jump off it

```
public class GroundCheck : MonoBehaviour {

Player player;
MovingPlatform mp;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    mp = FindObjectOfType<MovingPlatform>();
}


private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        player.isOnGround = true;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
    {
        player.isOnPlatform = true;
        transform.parent.SetParent(other.transform);
        mp.MoveThePlatform();
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        player.isOnGround = false;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
    {
        transform.parent.SetParent(null);
    }
}
```

}

and finally for platform movement (no RigidBody2Ds, just a collider)

```
public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour {

bool moving;

public Transform moveHere;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (moving)
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveHere.position, 2f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}


public void MoveThePlatform()
{
    moving = true;
}
```

}

additional images
[Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJZS3.png), [Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVrcU.png)

P.s. Forgot to add - on Player's RigidBody2D, under Constraints, check the "Freeze Rotation Z" box.